# What are other idiomatic expressions similar to "shed light on"

Tags: expressions, idioms

Are there any idioms or expressions similar to "shed light on"

Example: this evidence sheds light on the complicity of the accused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bring to the fore**

> To emphasize something or make it more noticeable.

*Be sure to bring this argument to the fore when you rewrite your paper*.

*Discrepancies in the yearly budget report brought questions of corruption to the fore*.

[The Free Dictionary]

Comment: Thank you very much